# Any tips on making mesh flush where they have been joined? Model is already high poly, and re-mesh is giving me undesirable results

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, remesh

[image]

[image]

Bear with me while I explain away. I modeled the head, body, and the hands separately. After finishing, I joined the objects together. I'm left with these seams where the objects are joined. Usually, I would've just remeshed and used the claystrips brush for a seamless finish. However, my model is somewhat highpoly already(have not done retopology yet). So, remeshing just gives me undesirable results.
[image]

Here, I used 0.04 as an example. Regardless of when I use either remesh under the sculpt tab or the remesh modifier, my look.. wonky. Extremely low poly, no matter how low I get it. I know I can adjust the number but too afraid of blender potentially crashing.

[image]

Here is the accurate vert/face count. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There's no single answer to your question. You're figuring out your modeling workflow, and the fact that detailing should be left until much later. Best is to remesh (you tried 4cm, it's obviously too coarse, try half a centimer), then keep sculpting until you've got the broad shapes correct, then retopo (the quad remesher should do if this character isn't meant to be posed/animated), then add detail using multires. Good luck